Probability and Stats Jobs in Industry
I have always enjoyed the probabilistic franework for modelling, in particular stochastic processes (I enjoyed studying Poisson Processes and its variations, Queueing theory, I did a course following the book Stochastic Modelling of Reaction-Diffusion Processes) as well as simulation of such processes.
Right now I am working as a data engineer/data scientist, but it's not really my cup of tea. I would like to go back to study such topics in more detail, as well as getting experience in such areas. However, I am having difficulty in both narrowing down what topics I would like to concentrate on as well as finding jobs that use such theory.
It seems that the main jobs (in industry) which are 'stochastic-heavy' are in finance (e.g. quant finance), which I don't neccesarily dislike but I would like to see other applications of the theory. Furthermore, it seems like other jobs which use stochastics are more oriented for engineers with math-intensive graduate programs rather than actual math graduates, for example, using monte carlo for the Neutron transport equation (I know this is a very specific and high-level example), which requires advanced knowledge on Physics.
Does anyone know of such jobs (I have a Bsc in Math and a Master in stats) and have some tips on how to start taking the first steps towards narrowing down on what you want to study?
Thanks in advance!
